# Twistd - using service.Application with Options to allow argument parsing

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twistd

I would like to run my server as a application. To do that, I have a `MyServer(name, port, host, testMode=False)` class (which inherits from `DatagramProtocol` object).

In another file I created a few commands to create and start my server. More or less, it looks like:

```
from twisted.application import service, internet

name, port, host = #read from database

server = MyServer(name, port, host)
udp_server = internet.UDPServer(port, server)
application = service.Application("MyServer")
udp_server.setServiceParent(application)
```

values `name, port`, and `host` I read from a database.
I start my server as `'twistd -y my_server_run.py'` and everything runs perfect.

However, I would like to be able to start my server in to modes: a testing mode and a standard one. Thus, I would like to pass an argument, which I read from the command line, to my object as an parameter. I found the information, that I cannot parse them as sys.argv, but I have to implement the `usage.Options`, so I did it as follows:

```
from twisted.application import service, internet
from twisted.python import usage

class Options(usage.Options):
    optParameters = [["test", "t", False, "The client test mode"]]


options = Options()
name, port, host = #read from database

try:
    options.parseOptions()
    server = MyServer(name, port, host, testMode=options['test'])
    udp_server = internet.UDPServer(port, server)
    application = service.Application("MyServer")
    udp_server.setServiceParent(application)
```

Then, I run my server as:

```
'twistd -y run_client.py --test True'
```

However, I'm getting error:

```
option -y not recognized
Unhandled Error
out: Traceback (most recent call last):
out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 648, in run
out:     runApp(config)
out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 25, in runApp
out:     _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 379, in run
out:     self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 444, in createOrGetApplication
out:     application = getApplication(self.config, passphrase)
out: --- <exception caught here> ---
out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 455, in getApplication
out:     application = service.loadApplication(filename, style, passphrase)
out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/service.py", line 411, in loadApplication
out:     passphrase)
out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/persisted/sob.py", line 224, in loadValueFromFile
out:     value = d[variable]
out: exceptions.KeyError: 'application'
out: Failed to load application: 'application'
out: Could not find 'application' in the file. To use 'twistd -y', your .tac
```

I cannot find out what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `service.Application` cannot be used with `usage.Options` as was already discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244050/twistd-using-usage-options-in-a-tac-file).

Options can be used if you are launching your server via

```
python run_client.py --test True
```

or if you use twisted plugins (TAP files).

You use [twisted application configuration](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html#twistd-and-tac) file, it is supposed you configure your server in this file and it will be launched as a service on production system. So it is OK to store options in some config file or database and read them during launch.